# Spring Data Store Redis - Use Multiple Caches

Tags: java, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

I have an application that is made up of two web servers, two redis caches, and a backend store. The two web servers, and two redis caches are located on the West and East coasts, in order to optimize performance. So far I have been able to connect to my first cache, from my web servers, and to my backend store. But I am looking for a way to use Spring to push data to both redis caches. I have configured both of my RedisManagers as follows.

```
@Bean(name="CacheManager1")
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    redisCacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(true);
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}

@Bean(name="CacheManager2")
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager2() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate2());
    redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    redisCacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(true);
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

Now I have tried a few random ways to cache to both places, but this particular way is failing with "Cacheable is not a Repeatable Annotation"

```
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "CacheManager1", value = "activityProfile", key = "#id")
@Cacheable(cacheManager = "CacheManager2", value = "activityProfile", key = "#id")
public ActivityProfile findActivityProfile(String id) {
    return activityProfileRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Is there any simple way to use Spring for this?

Comment: how about configuring a CacheResolver, which would return a list containing caches from both of those? haven't tried, but could work. See example [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-391?focusedCommentId=114319&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-114319)

Comment: you could create an annotation which could take an array of cacheManagers

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha I am interested by this... But my experience with annotations is limited. I started off creating the new annotation and let my IDE auto generate some items for me. But I am not sure where I would go an implement the logic, for example on set, to set the value in both caches. I am starting to search around online for guides on how to make annotations, but was just wondering if you knew of any particularly good guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dan Ciborowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1341806/dan-ciborowski-msft) - See here...

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-caching

The *Spring* reference explains how to combine multiple [Spring Cache Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache) annotations (e.g. `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut`, etc) using `@Caching`.

So for cacheable you may do the following.

```
    @Caching(cacheable = {@Cacheable("CacheManager1"), @Cacheable("CacheManager2")})
    public ActivityProfile findActivityProfile(String id) {
        return activityProfileRepository.findOne(id);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to just the right place. But after reading the details, it is not clear to me what behavior I should expect from using cacheable twice. (Put and Evic I think are obvious). Do you know if it will try and retrieve the data from all of my caches, but return a result when first response is received, or will it check the caches in order? Do I need order my caches differently depending on the region I would like them to use?

Comment: never seen anything like this before....can we add @Caching(cacheable = {@Cacheable(cacheManager="CacheManager1", value="a1",key="1"), @Cacheable(cacheManager="CacheManager2", value="a2",key="2")}) ?